# YouTube Api : snippet.live_chat_id is required

Tags: php, api, curl, youtube

I have been struggling with the youtube alot.
The problem is, i have made my own php curl script which should connect to the youtube api and send a livechat message to my current stream.

I am so close to finishing this issue but only this 1 last part stops me.

The script i currently use is:

```
$data = array("snippet" => ["type" => 'textMessageEvent', 'textMessageDetails' => ['messageText' => '<3']], 'livechatid' => '{{livechatid_here}}');
    $data_string = json_encode($data);

    $ch = curl_init('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveChat/messages?part=snippet&fields=authorDetails%2Ckind%2Csnippet&key={{Here is my key}}');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
            'Authorization: Bearer {{access_key}} ')
    );

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    dd($result);
```

But im constantly getting the following error:

```
  "code": 400,
  "message": "snippet.live_chat_id is required"\n
```

So what i did was i changed 'livechatid' to:

- liveChatId (as API tells me)
- live_Chat_Id
- livechatid
- snippet.livechatid
- snippet.liveChatId
- snippet.live_chat_id

And none of them worked.
Does anybody know how i can fix this?

Ofcourse i have been deleting my keys and access_tokens from the code above.

I have also tried adding them to the header but i still get the same error again and again.

Does anybody know how i can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Put `liveChatId` inside the `snippet` field :

```
$data = array("snippet" => [
  "type" => 'textMessageEvent',
  'textMessageDetails' => ['messageText' => '<3'],
  'liveChatId' => 'YOUR_LIVE_CHAT_ID'
]);
$data_string = json_encode($data);
```